# Make row labels italic in heatmap.2

Tags: r, plot, heatmap, plotmath, gplots

I'm trying to make my row labels italic using the R function `heatmap.2`. There's no default option and I can't figure out a work around by setting `par(font=3)` for example. How can I set my row labels to be italic in `heatmap.2`?

```
set.seed(123)
data = matrix(sample(100), nrow=10, ncol=10)
rownames(data) = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J")

library(gplots)

heatmap.2(data,
           Colv=TRUE,
           Rowv=TRUE,
           xlab=NA,
           ylab=NA)
```

Comment: `expression(italic())` works here. Just need to figure out a way to sneak it into `heatmap.2` function.

Comment: Unfortunately, that only results in a row labeled: italic("B"). Any suggestions on how to approach sneaking it into heatmap.2?

Comment: Run `heatmap2` without any arguments. The source code will apear. You need to change the `axis(...)` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `labCol` and `labRow` arguments to `heatmap.2` to pass in the labels. We just need to figure out how to pass these in as a list of `plotmath` expressions. I always find this painful, as I don't do it often enough to remember the appropriate incantations, but was able to put the code together by adapting [this R-help answer](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Plot-label-axis-with-expression-td4641046.html). Note that the matrix needs to have column names, which I've added in the code below

```
library(gplots)

# Fake data
set.seed(123)
data = matrix(sample(100), nrow=10, ncol=10)
rownames(data) = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J")
colnames(data) = 1:ncol(data)

heatmap.2(data,
          Colv=TRUE,
          Rowv=TRUE,
          labCol=as.expression(lapply(colnames(data), function(a) bquote(italic(.(a))))),
          labRow=as.expression(lapply(rownames(data), function(a) bquote(italic(.(a))))),
          xlab=NA,
          ylab=NA)
```

[image]